# Bar charts with timeline - Loggly

Tags: charts, loggly

I'm looking for a bar charts with timeline as Loggly.
Do you have some examples?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

There are many visualizations libraries that will allow you to do this. Many of these use D3.

For example, you can check out D3Plus:

http://d3plus.org/examples/basic/32517cfde67270c99092/